# How to send xml or image data from iphone to a rails 3 server?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, xml, post, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a hybrid app (rails 3 + iPhone) and I want to send a number of large strings and images to a rails 3 server. I want to do a POST method from iPhone. Can someone help me on how to do this ? since in this case there will be no form in the views how should I accept the data ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code for uploading an image through POST to an URL:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"example.png"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 0.9);

NSString *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://postingurl.com/posthere"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]    dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data;     name=\"fileid\"; filename=\"myfile.png\"\r\n"]
               dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:imageData];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil e    rror:nil];
[request release];

//Log return..
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(returnString);
[returnString release];
```

You add more lines for Content-Disposition to include other fields.

Comment: thank you. but do you know how to accept HTTP post requests in rails without forms ?

Comment: Ans: I figured out how to do this with ASIFormDataRequest  http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use